# Converting 12-hour time to 24-hour time using Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

Does anyone know how to convert string time formats in ArcMap v10.2 from 12-hour to 24-hour using a simple query in the Field Calculator? i.e. NO Python, NO editing in Excel, NO changing my Windows PC settings, etc...

This is a successful calculation I used (which I found on a discontinued forum) to convert my dates from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD:

**year([DateFld]) & "/" & Month([DateFld]) & "/" & Day([DateFld])**

Perhaps there is some sort of modification that I could make to the above calculation that would change my times to 24-hour?  I've searched for an answer everywhere and played around with it without any luck, but I would like for the times to be in **h:mm:ss** format.

Forgot to mention that this is a regular shapefile, not part of a GDB.

Comment: Are you willing to use the Python parser in the field calculator?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  To me, Python is trickier so I was hoping to avoid it completely.  Unless there is a generic line of script that I could copy and paste directly into the Field Calculator, I'd prefer to stick with VB Script.

Dan C's response below helped.

Comment: Can I see your attribute table to see how the dates are formatted?

Comment: Sorry, @ed.hankins, I no longer have access to this data...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually an ArcGIS tool specifically for this task: [Convert Time Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000v2000000). You don't even need to use the Field Calculator. Just specify the format of the source date/time field and your desired output format and the tool will create a new field and populate it with the converted values. It can be used for converting dates, times, or a combination of both.